# submit a form values to another page in php and inserting values from the new page

Tags: php

I have a user registration form `usertype` in `php`. after submitting I want the form to take its value to another page `user_med.php` and from this page I need to enter values to the table

here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="usertype" action="user_med.php " method="get" >
  <center>
    <h1> User Registration Page </h1>
    <div id="content">
      <input type="hidden" id="userreg" name="userreg" value="type" />
      <ul class="user">
        <li class="label">User id </li>
        <li class="field">
          <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" class="required error"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
      ..........
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `method=post` or `method=get`

Comment: So what have you done till now? Show us the code as well -_-

Comment: <body>
<form id="usertype" action="user_med.php " method="get" >
 <center>
 <h1> User Registration Page </h1>
 <div id="content">
 <input type="hidden" id="userreg" name="userreg" value="type" />  
       <ul class="user">
                <li class="label">User id </li>
                <li class="field">
                 <input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" class="required error"/></li></ul>
      ..........
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

go1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{  
 $_SESSION['name1']=$_POST['username'];
 header("Location: go2.php");
}
?> 


<form action="#" onsubmit="" method="post">   
<b>Enter your name: </b>
<br> 
<input type="text" name="username">
<br> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

go2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Result:<br>";
echo $_SESSION['name1'];

echo'<br><a href="go1.php">Go back</a>';

?>
```

Comment: in your case: $userid = $_POST["userid"]; would be: $_SESSION['name1'] = $_POST["userid"];

Comment: <?php $usertype = $_POST["usertype"]; $userid = $_POST["userid"]; $empname = $_POST["empname"]; $username = $_POST["username"]; $password = $_POST["password"]; $radiobt = $_POST["radiobt"]; $doa = $_POST["doa"]; $createdby = $_POST["createdby"]; echo "Usertype:".$usertype ." <br>"; echo "userid :".$userid ." <br>" ; echo "empname :".$empname." <br>" ; echo "username:".$username." <br>" ; echo "password:".$password ." <br>"; echo "Status:".$radiobt." <br>" ; echo "doa:".$doa ." <br>"; echo "createdby:".$createdby." <br>"; ?>

Comment: used the above code,but its not ouptting the values.

Comment: Undefined index: usertype in C:\wamp\www\cast\user_med.php on line 4

Comment: i have placed a new sample code, with form and result page.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22604863/3437255

Comment: Its working   :      
echo $_POST['usertype'];
echo $_POST['userid'];
echo $_POST['empname'];
echo $_POST['username'];
echo $_POST['password'];
echo $_POST['radiobt'];
echo $_POST['doa'];
echo $_POST['createdby'];

Comment: So the problem is resolved? Sample can be viewed here : http://wistudat.be/try/go1.php

Answer (score 0):

You can give form action to a different page

```
<form action="user_med.php">
</form>
```

Or you can use jquery $.ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//#usertype will be the form id
$('#usertype').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'user_med.php',
            data: $("#usertype").serialize(),
            success:function(data, status)
            {
                alert(data);
                //Do success action here...
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can I display the values in user_med.php

Comment: You can use $_post['form_field_name'];

Answer (score 0):

create a session variable and move the values to it
$_SESSION['name1']=$data
$_SESSION['name2']=$data
.....

start the session on the next page as
session_start();

Then retrieve values from the above created session variables as

echo $_SESSION['name1'];
....

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:-----

```
<form action="user_med.php" method="post">
</form>
```

And at the `"user_med.php"` page you may get the all values of the form using the following syntax:--

```
$var=$_POST['field_name'];
```

then you may insert all values into the table...

I hope that it will help you.

Comment: <?php


$usertype = $_POST["usertype"];
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$empname = $_POST["empname"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$radiobt = $_POST["radiobt"];
$doa = $_POST["doa"];
$createdby = $_POST["createdby"];

echo "Usertype:".$usertype  ." <br>";
echo "userid :".$userid ." <br>" ;
echo "empname :".$empname." <br>" ;
echo "username:".$username." <br>" ;
echo "password:".$password ." <br>";
echo "Status:".$radiobt." <br>" ;
echo "doa:".$doa ." <br>";
echo "createdby:".$createdby." <br>";



?>

Comment: Undefined index: usertype in C:\wamp\www\cast\user_med.php on line 4

Comment: i think some field name mismatching